# Java vertx mongoclient like query

Tags: java, vert.x

Is there any way to find a document in mongoclient with regular expressions?
Something similar to LIKE query in sql

I tried following code, but its not working:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("/raj/");
        JsonObject query = new JsonObject().put("firstName", regex.toString());
        mongoClient.find("users",query, res -> {
            if(res.succeeded()){
                future.complete(res.result());
            }else{
                future.fail(res.cause());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
JsonObject query = new JsonObject().put("firstName", new JsonObject()
   .put("$regex", ".*" + searchKeyword + ".*"
   )
);
```

also in mongo shell this works:

```
db.users.find({"firstName": { "$regex": ".*raj.*"}})
```